# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault!!')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preventdefault

I keep getting the above below when I run this code
I don't see anything wrong with it and I don't know why its returning the above error. it use to work before, but after coming back to it today, it gave me this error.
Is there an issue with this?

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'preventDefault!!')`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { axiosWithAuth } from "./auth/axiosWithAuth";
import { useHistory, useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import { deleteItem, getItems, addItems} from "./state/actionCreators";


const FetchData = props => {
const { id } = useParams();
const [ item ] = useState([])

function addItems(e, item){
  e.preventDefault();
  addItems(item)
}


        return (
            // <Link to={`/Cart/${props.item}`}>
              <div className="item-card-container">
              <StyledItems className="styled-card">
              <h4>{props.item.title}</h4>
              <img src ={props.item.image} alt= '' />
              <h4>{props.item.description}</h4>
              <h4>${props.item.price}</h4>
              <h4>{props.item.category}</h4>

              <button onClick={(e, item) => addItems(e, item)}>
                        Add to cart
                    </button>
        </StyledItems>
        </div>
    // </Link>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addItem: item => dispatch(addItems(item))
});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FetchData);
```

Comment: sorry about the editing
i Hope you guys understand

Comment: You have two `addItems`, one is an action and one is a click listener. Change one of the functions' name.

Comment: How do you mean

Comment: `addItems} from "./state/actionCreators";` and `function addItems(e, item){` are named the same. Please consider renaming the one of them?

Comment: Its not working
I cant add any item

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: `addItems(item)` is calling the function two lines above `addItem(e, item) {...}`. item doesn't have a preventDefault function and is actually undefined because the onClick event is only given one argument.

Comment: `onClick={(e, item) => addItems(e, item)}` will be `onClick={(ClickEvent, undefined) => addItems(ClickEvent, undefined)}` it should be `onClick={(e) => addItems(e, item)}`

Comment: Also buttons (outside of forms) do not have defaults that need to be prevented

Comment: @AryeEidelman
  <button onClick={(e) => addItems(e, item)}>
            Add to cart
           </button>
I have changed it to this
but i get this error  TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: @evolutionxbox
I changed the name of one of them as u told me to
when i click the button it doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

Fix naming conflicts

Only accept one argument in event handler

Call the redux action creater functions **from the props** (after they have the dispatch wrapper) not directly from the imports. Otherwise they will simply return the action without dispatching them to the store.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { axiosWithAuth } from "./auth/axiosWithAuth";
import { useHistory, useParams} from "react-router-dom";
import { deleteItem, getItems, addItems} from "./state/actionCreators";


const FetchData = props => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const [ item ] = useState([])

    function addItemHandler(e, item){
        e.preventDefault();
        props.addItem(item)
    }


        return (
            // <Link to={`/Cart/${props.item}`}>
              <div className="item-card-container">
              <StyledItems className="styled-card">
              <h4>{props.item.title}</h4>
              <img src ={props.item.image} alt= '' />
              <h4>{props.item.description}</h4>
              <h4>${props.item.price}</h4>
              <h4>{props.item.category}</h4>

              <button onClick={(e) => addItemHandler(e, item)}>
                   Add to cart
              </button>
        </StyledItems>
        </div>
    // </Link>
  );
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addItem: item => dispatch(addItems(item))
});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(FetchData);
```

Consider using react redux hooks for a simpler API [useDispatch](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usedispatch)